# Why must the base class object be a reference to call the derived virtual function?

Tags: c++, class, reference, overriding, virtual

Why must the base class object be a reference to call the derived virtual function ?

```
   #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class A {

    public:
        virtual void print() { cout << "Hello 1" << endl; }

    };

    class B : public A {

    public:
        int x;
        void print() { cout << "Hello " << x << endl; }

    };

    void main(){

        B obj1;
        A &obj2 = obj1;
        A obj3 = obj1; // Why it is different from obj2

        obj1.x = 2;

        obj1.print();
        obj2.print();
        obj3.print(); // ?

    }
```

Comment: Because polymorphism works only for references and pointers.

Comment: "Why does X require Y?" "Because Y is a requirement of X." Not a very helpful comment

Answer (score 5):

When you assign a derived object to a base variable, it gets "[sliced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)" into an instance of the base class; it's no longer an instance of the derived one.  That's necessary because the base variable only has enough space reserved for an instance of the base class; an instance of a derived class, with its additional data, won't fit.

When you use a reference, the object doesn't have to be copied into a smaller space, so slicing doesn't occur.

Answer (score 3):

```
A obj3 = obj1; // Why it is different from obj2
```

Constructs obj3 by **copying**. In this case obj1 is upcast to an A type where obj3 in constructed from obj1's "A" parameters. This phenomena is known as [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

```
A &obj2 = obj1;
```

This line binds the reference obj2 to an instance of obj1. You've upcasted obj1 to an "A" by pointing obj2 to it. Keep in mind in C++ a reference is really just an alias. You've just given obj1 a different name where that name is bound to a base class type.

So `A obj3` allocates and constructs a brand new object on the stack while `A &obj2` just creates a reference/alias for some other thing that already exists.